# Manejo de roles en rutas de Angular 4+ (JWT)

Tags: laravel, web, angular, typescript, jwt

Me gustaría saber cual es la mejor manera de manejar los roles de usuario en Angular?.

El escenario es el siguiente:
Tengo una apliación en Angular que consume un API REST hecho con Laravel, el mismo que me proporciona un token. La aplicación manejará 3 tipos de roles (administrador, estudiante, docente), las rutas estan protegidas por un servicio **Guard**

```
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'admin', component: DashAdminComponent, children: [
      {
        path: 'estudiantes', component: EstudiantesComponent, children: [
          { path: 'nuevo-estudiante', component: NuevoEstudianteComponent, canActivate: [GuardService] },
          { path: 'todos', component: ListaComponent, canActivate: [GuardService] },
          { path: 'editar/:id', component: EditarComponent, canActivate: [GuardService],  }
        ], canActivate: [GuardService]
      },
      { path: 'docentes', component: DocentesComponent, children:[
        { path: 'nuevo-docente', component: NuevoDocenteComponent, canActivate: [GuardService] },
        { path: 'lista-docente', component: ListaDocenteComponent, canActivate: [GuardService] },

      ], canActivate: [GuardService] }


    ], canActivate: [GuardService]
  },
```

El servicio **Guard** verifica si el token esta presente y es valido

```
  canActivate() {
    if (this.apiSerive.getLogged()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Sin embargo esta lógica (comprobar si el token es valido y esta presente) podría permitir que un usuario con rol **estudiante** pueda acceder a una ruta destinada a usuarios de rol **administrador**.

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entregas los privilegios del usuario junto a los datos de usuario cuando te autoriza el API, puedes hacer algo similar a:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let authorization = this.isLoggedIn();
    const privileges = route.data['privileges'];

    if(privileges){
      for(let priv of privileges) {
        authorization = authorization && this.getUser().hasPrivilege(priv);
      }
    }
    if (authorization) { return true ; }
    return false;
  }

  canAccess(privilege){
    return this.getUser().hasPrivilege(privilege);
  }
```

Y en tu módulo, específicamente en las rutas, algo similar a:

```
canActivate: [AuthService],
data: {privileges: ['administrador'] }
```

**EDICIÓN**

Arriba instancié route como **ActivatedRouteSnapshot**.

Según la documentación ActivatedRouteSnapshot y traducido mas o menos de forma entendible, contiene la información sobre la ruta asociada a un componente cargado en cierto momento. También puede ser usado para recorrer el árbol de estados de route.

Una de sus propiedades es **data** que contiene los datos estaticos y resueltos de la ruta cargada.

En data podemos, entonces, **guardar datos que nos sean de utilidad**, como **privilegios**, o para ser mas fiel a tu esquema, **roles**.

**Por ejemplo**, arriba, en mi canActivate trabajo con privileges, pero tú podrías cambiar todos esos privileges y llamarlos roles sin problema.
Hay una parte donde pregunto si `this.getUser().hasPrivilege(priv);`, bueno, ese método lo tengo en mi modelo User (user.ts) y es algo así:

```
hasPrivilege(key: string) : boolean{
    if (!this.privileges) { return false; }        
    return this.privileges.filter(p => p.key === key).length > 0;
}
```

**Privilegio** es una propiedad de mi modelo user que entre otras cosas tiene:

```
export class User {
    id: number = null;
    name: string;
    full_name: string;
    email: string;
    privileges: Array<Privilege> = [];
    password: string;
```

...
Que es otro modelo que tiene:

```
export class Privilege {
    id: number;
    key: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

Como ves, **en resumen** **obtengo mi usuario del servidor**, canActivate se encarga de **preguntar si el usuario** (que viene con sus privilegios desde el servidor y me encargo de instanciarlo correctamente) **tiene algún(os) determinado(s) privilegio(s) necesario(s) para la ruta en particular** y **devuelve true o false** dependiendo de si **cumple con los requisitos**.
Esos privilegios de esa ruta en particular que menciono, son los que defino en la propiedad **data** en la ruta por la cual preguntabas... básicamente estoy diciendo, cuando preguntes si el usuario canActivate, indica que requiere este(estos) privilegio(s)/rol(es).

Comment: Gracias Julio. Te entiendo perfectamente. Me podrias explicar el uso del parametro **data: {privileges: ['adminstrador]}**?

Comment: Edité la respuesta, quizás fui un poco enredado pero espero que se logre encaminarte.